# Is it possible remove " ./ " when executing a program using makefile?

Tags: linux, makefile

I have a makefile which produces an executable "submission", I want to run this file by typing     "submission [arguments] " instead of "./submission [arguments]", if it is possible how can I do this ?

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS= -g -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic

CODE_SRC = code.cpp

CODE_OBJ = code.o

code: $(CODE_OBJ)
    $(CXX) -o submission $(CXXFLAGS) $(CODE_OBJ) -lm
    @echo "-----------DONE -------------"
.cc.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS)  -c $*.cpp
clean:
    rm -f *.o submission
clobber:
    rm -f *.o
```

Comment: this is property of Unix/Linux shell. To run any run-able file (binary or script) located at current directory you have to prefix it with `./`. Only excusable found by `PATH` variable are run without this prefix, for example `ls`.

Comment: Try including.`./` in`$PATH`

Comment: Please don't include . in $PATH.  At a minimum, its a security issue.  I would downvote that comment if I could.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/656303/how-to-run-an-executable-without-prepending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't related to the `Makefile`, but related to how your shell determines which programs you might want to run. When you run a command like `ls`, the shell knows where this program is due to the `PATH` environment variable.

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

So in this case, my `ls` program has to be in one of the following directories:

- `/usr/local/bin`
- `/usr/bin`
- `/bin`
- `/usr/sbin`
- `/sbin`

If it wasn't in one of these directories, I would have to do what you do and specify the path to it.

In my case:

```
$ /bin/ls
```

In your case, your program is not in your `PATH`, so you need to specify where it is, which is your current directory (that's what `./` means).

If you want to run this program without specifying a path, you need your program to be in a directory in your `PATH`. Generally, you probably don't want to drop your random executables in one of the default directories. Instead, you can add a new directory to the `PATH`.

In your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`, add the line:

```
export PATH="~/bin:$PATH"
```

You can replace `~/bin` with whatever path you wish, but I usually like to have a single place for my own executables. Then, you'll want to put the executable in that directory (if it is different from the one it already is in). You will need to re-open your terminal to get the `PATH` updated. After this, you should be able to run your program as expected.

Fun Fact: Adding `./` to your `PATH` will let you run executables without their path in whichever directory you're currently in!

Answer (score 1):

> I want to run this file by typing `submission [arguments]`.

You can run it using `make run_submission` if you fix one rule and add another:

```
submission: $(CODE_OBJ) # Uses correct target name.
    $(CXX) -o $@ $(CXXFLAGS) $(CODE_OBJ) -lm

run_submission: submission # Builds submission first.
    ./submission <args>

.PHONY: clean clobber run_submission
```